# a moderator deleted my answer under false pretence: offensive/spam

Tags: discussion, deleting, specific-answer

I have a question about my Academia Stack Exchange post: [Is "Assistant Professor Position (Tenure Track) for a female Researcher" illegal in Austria?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/100529/is-assistant-professor-position-tenure-track-for-a-female-researcher-illegal/100709#100709)

A moderator kept deleting my answer under the pretence it's spam/offensive. I don't believe it's spam. And if s/he thinks it offends him/her, please explain why?
Here is the text of the answer:

> All people are equal, but some people are more equal than others. Therefore, it is only natural that some actions that are inherently negative see themselves become positive. This is justified by "the end justifies the means" Doctrine which clearly states: that all actions are justified for the greater good.
>
> In fact, I'm puzzled why would you want to sue such a moral endeavour. Especially, if you see its success in the United states' undergrad admission.Where the proportion of bachelor's degrees earned has went from an opressive 55% male majority in 1974 to a healthy 57% female majority in 2014, thanks to the affirmative action policy that continues to this day.
>
> and it baffles me even more, If you see the great benefits that "trying to control demographics in order to level inequalities" has brought upon humanity as seen in advanced countries like Germany or Israel.
>
> One might perhaps argue that this is "a form of separate but equal". But this is easily disproven by noting that women can still apply to the other non-gender-specific job postings.
>
> to answer your question, such an effective and moral actions cannot be illegal unless you go by the rotten principle that "all men are equal. full stop". A heinous saying that does not try to hide its patriarchal motives by the use of the word "men".
>
> You questioning "the separation of job postings based on sex" seems quite sexist to me. I advise you to check your privilege.
>
> Although, I might concede that such a posting might be a bit unethical because it might hurt the transgender and non-binary people.

Answer (score 18):

Your answer is full of arguments that take an argument that is typically made by the side which you claim to oppose and present it as an argument for the other side.
Moreover you are throwing clichéic, unjustified accusations at the asker.
This is so blatant that it is almost certainly intentional¹.
I don’t know whether you do this to provoke conflict, to mock others, or because you severely misunderstood the concept of devil’s advocate.
But whatever your motivation, it’s [not nice](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice):
It’s not respectful of others and harmful to this community.

---

<sup>¹ in the unlikely event that it isn’t, please stop; you are not helping your cause</sup>

Answer (score 15):

Your original answer was flagged by two users as rude/offensive. This brought it to my attention. Upon looking at the answer it seemed unrelated to the question and designed to produce discussion. This is taking advantage of our community and considered rude. Therefore I cast a 3rd flag as rude which caused the community bot to delete your question.

Comment: could you please explain. how is my question rude? to whom exactly is it, rude? maybe I've gone overboard by calling op sexist, but a simple commnet would have been enough for me to tone it down.

Comment: @LeonMeier You get that their post was entirely sarcastic and that they were basically agreeing with you, right?